# Libre messenger program with loads of emoticons

Tags: windows, open-source, chat

I am looking for a messenger program that:

1. Is End-to-end encrypted
2. Is Libre (FLOSS) - given Snowden's revelations it would be naive to trust E2E without the source code
3. Has loads of cute emoticons - This is a requirement for user acceptance (Yes it really is!)
4. Runs on Microsoft Windows

It would be nice if it worked without a central server (similar to https://ricochet.im/).

"Loads of cute emoticons" is a bit hard to quantify, but apparently Skype qualifies for that point. (But Skype fails on point 2).

A few examples that do *not* qualify:

- IRC with OTR (fails on 3)
- Skype (fails on 2)
- Facebook Messenger (fails on 2)
- Ricochet.im (fails on 3 - unless there is some add-on I do not know)

In the answer please include a link to the source code and a link to a screen shot of "cute emoticons".

Comment: Um, doesn't 4 contradict 1 and 2? Just saying ;)

Comment: Ricochet.im runs on Microsoft Windows. Ricochet.im is end-to-end encrypted and libre software. So Ricochet.im provides 1,2, and 4 (+ the serverless bonus).

Comment: @OleTange I was rather pointing at Windows not being open-source and MS siphoning off data ("telemetry" etc) and controlling your PC – so E2E doesn't help much with the spy sitting on (at least) one end.

Comment: @Izzy Just because we are all going to die anyway, it does not mean we might as well  commit suicide.

Comment: Certainly not (but neither we need picnic on the graveyard) :D Sorry that I could not resist the note – and I hope I didn't offend! Shall I remove this chain of comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using https://ricochet.im/. It actually does meet 3, because of these interesting bits of Unicode called emojis. On Windows 10, you can pick emojis by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, There are more than 3K of them, so hopefully that qualifies as "loads".

<sub>(Sorry, this should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an [Emoji App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/emoji-viewer/9nblggh6csf9?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) + [Riot](https://about.riot.im/), or any other FOSS chat app.

PS: If you are so concerned about privacy I would [switch to Linux](https://itsfoss.com/linux-better-than-windows/). It is just as easy to use as windows, and it has a better support community.  I would recommend [Majaro Linux's](https://manjaro.org) [KDE Plasma Edition](https://manjaro.org/download/#kde-plasma) (that's what I use)

Oh, I almost forgot to mention that [You still can't turn spyware off in Windows](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3159424/you-still-can-t-turn-off-windows-10-s-built-in-spyware.html). So never mind your chats being recorded, [Microsoft's Spyware](https://www.quora.com/Is-Microsoft-Windows-10-basically-a-spying-operating-system) records your whole life!

Comment: We unfortunately have one killer application that does not run on GNU/Linux.

Comment: @OleTange That stinks. What is it?

Comment: Locally developed software from a national company.

Comment: Have you tried wine?

Answer (score 0):

We experienced trouble adding people on Ricochet.im and qTox.

We are currently testing Riot.im. Given @Perhaps-you-see-this-name input on <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> it may be OK.